# Python GEKKO using function in model with if-statement

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I am trying to solve a nonlinear optimization problem with GEKKO Python. I know that I can pass my own function to an Intermediate or Objective function, but since my intermediate is a piecewise function, I need if-statements.

For example:

#### This works from what I've tested.

```
def calc_weighted_average(values, characteristic):
  # values are the model's variables that are changed by GEKKO.
  # characteristic are always the same (they are a constant list I've defined).
  sum = 0
  for i in range(values):
    sum += values[i] * characteristic[i]

  return sum / m.sum(values)

weighted_average_density = m.Intermediate(calc_weighted_average(values, density_list))
```

#### This doesn't work and I am not sure how to get this to work?

```
def calc_weighted_average(values, characteristic):
  # values are the model's variables that are changed by GEKKO.
  # characteristic are always the same (they are a constant list I've defined).
  sum = 0
  for i in range(values):
    sum += values[i] * characteristic[i]

  # Correction factor when too large
  if sum > 5:
    correction_factor = (sum - 5) * (0.984 ** 2)
  else:
    correction_factor = 0

  return (sum / m.sum(values)) - correction_factor

weighted_average_density = m.Intermediate(calc_weighted_average(values, density_list))
```

Comment: Have you tried the gekko `if3()` function? https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html

Comment: @JohnHedengren I just tried that and it looks like it works as expected. Are there any caveats I should know when using the `m.if3()` function inside a user-defined function passed into an `m.intermediate()`?

Also, Thanks!

Edited for clarity.

Comment: The `m.if3()` function requires a binary variable so it can get slower as the problem size increases significantly. Make sure you use `m.options.SOLVER=1` (APOPT solver) as an MINLP solver for these types of problems. Calling the `m.if3()` function changes the default to APOPT but you just need to make sure you aren't forcing `m.options.SOLVER=3` or other NLP solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `m.if3()` function. Instead of:

```py
if sum > 5:
  correction_factor = (sum - 5) * (0.984 ** 2)
else:
  correction_factor = 0
```

try the following code:

```py
correction_factor = m.if3(sum-5,0,(sum-5)*(0.984**2))
```

The `m.if2()` function is also available as a logical condition with a Mathematical Program with Complementary Constraints (MPCC). The `m.if3()` function uses a binary variable instead and generally performs better, but can slow down with many binary variables for large scale problems.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much John!

Also, I appreciate you bringing up the SOLVER setting. I already did that but it's good to know that I didn't choose the wrong one.